# Binding Shift to my mouse 1 and quick switch LUA script

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to create a LUA script that binds my shift to mouse1 kind of like strafe stop in csgo. I was successful making the script but the only problem is when I hold mouse 1, my characters movement is equivalent of pressing shift which I Want to avoid. Is it possible to bind my shift to mouse1 for tapping only not while spraying(holding mouse1) and for the quick switch I can’t seem to find a solution to this, when I click mouse 2, it just presses q without shooting (pressing mouse 1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImHHk.jpg any solution? Thank you.  **
This is the quick switch script i have been working on, i want my script to be able to quickswitch to previous weapon when scoped and after i hit the mouse button 1.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)



if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 ) then PressMouseButton(1) 


                   PressKey("q")
Sleep(5)
ReleaseKey("q")
end
end
```

And this is the strafestop with shift . lost my script from yesterday this doesn't do anything. I want to be able to tap and have pressedkey shift at the while tapping mouse 1  but not while spraying(holding mouse 1) don't even know if its possible

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)


if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then 
Sleep(1)
      PressKey("lshift") 
      Sleep(5)
      ReleaseKey("lshift") 
end
end
```

Comment: edited my questtion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

local LMB_pressed_at

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      LMB_pressed_at = GetRunningTime()
   end
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 1 and GetRunningTime() - LMB_pressed_at < 200 then
      PressKey("lshift")
      Sleep(15)
      ReleaseKey("lshift")
   end
end
```

Comment: Thankyou so much.

Comment: Hey would you be able to help me with 1 more script?